# Scheduling Batch scripts WIndows , how to

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have a batch script shortcut that I put into the start-up folder .. This successfully runs a RWeverything command at boot .

```
Rw.exe -/Min /Nologo /Stdout /Command="WRMSR 0x610 0x0 0x005F8A00 0"

Rw.exe -/Min /Nologo /Stdout /Command="W16 0xFED170A8 0000"
```

However I wanted this same script to run after the computer wakes from sleep . I got this idea from the following post below in link ( from a techtablets forum post)

> run it by task scheduler on “System event” and then
> “Microsoft-power-troubleshooter =1″, makes the batch run after every
> ‘wake up’, so after start up, or sleep, or hybernate. So it always
> runs at your desired speed, even after sleep.

[RWeverything TDP hack thread , quote 182284](https://techtablets.com/forum/topic/good-news-found-a-way-to-increase-tdp-limit-on-ezbook-3-pro-maybe-any-n3450/)

However I am not understanding how to do the above , would someone care to elaborate ? Additionally to being run after waking up from sleep , I would like a delay of say 45 seconds

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are step-by-step guides online, e.g., https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/schedule-a-batch-file-to-run-automatically-in-windows-10-11.html  . You can set a *time* delay: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-delay-a-scheduled-task-in-windows-10-task-scheduler . The task can also be set to start after an *event*. Pick an event that finishes after wake up, for example, and use that as the trigger: https://woshub.com/schedule-task-to-start-when-another-task-finishes/

Comment: Thanks , it seems part of the solution is here also https://sumtips.com/how-to/run-program-windows-wakes-up-sleep-hibernate/

Comment: Ok after the task within task scheduler , the task starts but does not complete.. The CMD window opens for a split second and exits .. Not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: Are you starting the script from the wrong path, and as such it can't find rw.exe? Write a pause at the end of your script, so the window remains open. make sure you remove the pause when it works, because otherwise, the task will never complete. Also, keep in mind that if a task starts and directly stops, you have to refresh task scheduler to see that it stopped.